# Delphi 6, ADO, MS database "Date" field is same as ftWideString

Tags: sql-server, delphi, date, ado, field

I want to copy elements to a remote MS-SQL database.
I got conversion error on it.

When I checked the ADOTable structure I saw the MS field

```
WHENCREATED DATE [NULL]
```

is converted to

```
ftWideString 10
```

Hmmmmm....

Is it normal? Or I can set something to Date fields are come as TDateTime?

The Provider is "SQLOLEDB.1"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Its a `DATE` (yyyy-mm-dd) type which was introduced in SQL Server 2008 as an alternative to the `DATETIME` type.

Because `SQLOLEDB.1` precedes this there is a [backward conversion](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180878.aspx#BackwardCompatibilityforDownlevelClients) to `DBTYPE_WSTR`, using an updated provider (SQLNCLI) would be preferable.

Comment: Delphi 6 is 10 years old. SQL Server 2008 3 years. Unsurprisingly this causes problems.